# Efficient way to get metadata of tables (all tables name) from oracle data base and store it in a java arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, database, oracle, jsp

I am developing a java web application and for some reason I need to get the names of all the tables in oracle database created by a user under a java list.

> Query I'm using (To be noted, there are 2k or more tables)

```
SELECT table_name FROM user_tables; //I hope I'm not wrong with query.
```

Which is working fine and I'm getting the desired results. Now I need to store it in a Java ArrayList and when I do that, it is taking long time to get the job done, like minutes.

I choose array list over linked List, because comparatively adding elements to array list requires less job than to Linked List. So is there any efficient way to accomplish this task, because later I will do this for getting Column names too.

Comment: If you know that you have ~2k table names, you could set the initial size of the arraylist to around the expected value, this would reduce the time, needed to increase the size (and copying of data) of the underlying array.

Comment: But I need it to be dynamic, what if the number of tables increases in future? I cannot tweak in the code every time? That's the problem. With your suggestion what I can do is get count of tables present every time, initialize array list size with that value and continue further. Is there a better way than this? @Lino

Comment: Do you know if the time is spent waiting on the database or on Java?  I'd be surprised if Java takes more than a second to store such a small amount of data.  But I can imagine cases where Oracle may take minutes to return all the results from that query - `USER_TABLES` is really about 20 different objects combined, and in rare cases Oracle can build a bad execution plan for getting metadata.  Are you sure the query is really working fine?  (One common problem is that the query may quickly return the top N results shown by an IDE, but takes longer to produce all the results.)

Comment: @Jon Heller Yes. I have checked the query. It is really working fine. As you said, I guess it is the database that is taking time to fetch than on Java part. So what should be the solution for this?